# Reporting Services string concatenation issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to write an expression to concatenate a string but I get an error message when I save the report. What could be the problem? Thanks for any help.

```
=Fields!address.Value&","&Fields!city.Value&","&Fields!zipcode.Value&","&Fields!state.Value
```

Comment: also are you using the expression builder writing this out by hand

Comment: You don't really have the & at the end of the .Value without whitespace between them right?  It won't work unless the .Value is separated from the & with whitespace.

Comment: I added a whitespace, it works now. Thanks David

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .Value must be separated from the & with whitespace, otherwise it will not work.